# What is the difference between these two ways of mapping functions in scala?

Tags: scala

Here in the Scala Koans for Lazy Sequences [they have](https://github.com/FPerezP/scala-koans/blob/master/AboutLazySequences.scala):

```
var x = 0
def inc = {x += 1; x}

val strictList = List(inc _, inc _, inc _)
strictList.map(f => f).head should be(_)
```

This last line

```
strictList.map(f => f).head
```

returns a function.

Now this last line compiles - but to achieve the goal they want in the koan you have to modify it to:

```
strictList.map(f => f()).head should be(1)
```

(ie you add the parens after the second reference to `f`. )

What would cause that difference? (Assuming it is not a mistake). Has the Scala language changed?

My question is: **What is the difference between these two ways of mapping functions in scala?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strictList` is a list of anonymous functions. In the first case:

```
strictList.map(f => f).head
```

you're just mapping over the list and returning the function.  In the second case:

```
strictList.map(f => f()).head
```

you're actually invoking each anonymous function and building up a list of the results of calling each function.

There seems to be a mistake in the file you link to.  Line 19:

```
strictList.map(f => f).head should be(3)
```

is incorrect.  The value should be an anonymous function, not `3`.

Comment: Thanks @adrice727 that's helpful. My question is - was this once valid scala code and now is invalid due to a change in the language spec?

Comment: @hawkeye I think I understand the issue now.  Both lines are valid Scala.  The issue is with the code you link to.  See my updated answer.